# Change image src using JQuery Attributes and an HTML input

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

Good evening.

I am looking for a bit of help in a Code I found around, but I can't get towork as I would like:

This code, essentially, let's you insert in the Input the URL of an image (Let's say "http://i.blogs.es/e79516/nuevo-logo-google/650_1200.jpg") and once you left the input, the script automatically shows it up in the image below.

The problem, is that I would like to **enter only the name of the archive, not the entire URL**, but I don't know how or where to enter all the URL route and left only the dynamic part to change, since I am beginning with Js.

So, imagining I want to show only images already created and ubicated in "//localhost/ROL/images/Avatars/Characters/**"NAME OF THE ARCHIVE"**.png", Which changes should I make to only enter the file name, without even the extension?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento sin título</title>
<script src="js/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/jquery-ui.css">
</head>
<body>
<tr>
        <td valign="top">
            Profile Picture:<br>
            <span class="small3">(will be reduced to 50x50)</span>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input size="100" id="newProfilePicture" name="profpic" value="/%profpic%/"> 
            <br>
            <img id="profilePicture" src="/%profimg%/">
        </td>
    </tr>
</body>
<script>
$('#newProfilePicture').blur(function() {
        var newSrc = $('#newProfilePicture').val();
        $('#profilePicture').attr('src',newSrc);
    });
</script>
</html>
```

Thank you for the Attention

Comment: what about `<input type="file" />`, would be useful for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.blur(function(){
    $('#profilePicture').prop('src',"i.blogs.es/e79516/nuevo-logo-google/"+$('#newProfilePicture').val()+".png");
});
```

Works but not necessary to save the value to a variable.
You also may want to use prop() instead of attr.
(Sorry I missed your OP question asking to tack on the ".png")

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! As you said, it's working very nicely, but if I also would like to add the ".png" at the end of the source, so I get to type only the name, Should I edit the line like:

    .prop('src',"i.blogs.es/e79516/nuevo-logo-google/"+$('#newProfilePicture').+".png".val());

Or how?

Comment: Think of your input as a chunk of the whole URL. That chunk comes from jQuery evaluating the input: `$('#newProfilePicture').val()` That chunk needs to be exactly that. So if you want to add the ".png", it goes after the chunk of jQ: ...`$('#newProfilePicture').val()+".png"`

Comment: Thank you for the help! Upvoted and marked as solution ;)

Comment: I tried to edit my comment. This may help make more sense: Think of what your are trying to do as putting building blocks or chunks together. The directory path is a static chunk you put in front. Then your input is the next chunk of the whole URL. That chunk comes from jQuery evaluating the input: `$('#newProfilePicture').val()` That chunk needs to be exactly that. Then to add the ".png", that is like the end chunk that goes after the chunk of jQ. Put it all together with `+` and voila you have your URL